# fadeIn of an element after fading out another one isn't really working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I've created a website called "Pumpn Records" and it's almost finished. On the website there is a section called "Releases". It is divided in two sections, but only one is visible.
So this is the website: http://s448350928.online.de/pumpn/records/index3

The Releases Section there has this html code (simplified):

```
<div class="container1" id="releases">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script>
function hide2014and2016show2015()
 {
 $("#2014").fadeOut(4000);
 }
</script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#2015").hide();// hide it initially
 $('#forward2014').click(function(){
    $("#2015").delay(4000).fadeIn(4000);                            });
 });
</script>
<h2>Releases</h2>
<div id="yearcontainer">
<div id="back2014" style="display:inline-block">
<img id="back2014img" src="..."/>
</div>
<h2 id="year">2014</h2>
<div id="forward2014" onclick="hide2014and2016show2015();" style="display:inline-block">
<img id="forward2014img" src="..."/>
</div>
</div>
<div id="2014">
    <div class='container3' style="overflow:visible;">
        <h2>EPs</h2>
        <div class='row2'>
            <a href="...">
                <img width="300px" src="..."/>
                <h2>Nano Miratus</h2>
                <h3>Ganz Okay EP (Instrumental)</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class='row2'>
            <a href="...">
                <img width="300px" src="..."/>
                <h2>Nano Miratus</h2>
                <h3>Ganz Okay EP</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class='row2'>
            <a href="...">
                <img width="300px" src="..."/>
                <h2>Nano Miratus</h2>
                <h3>Viernacheins EP</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="2015">
    <div class='container3' style="overflow:visible;">
        <h2>Alben</h2>
        <div class='row2'>
            <a href="...">
                <img width="300px" src="..."/>
                <h2>Nano Miratus</h2>
                <h3>Larmoyanz</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='container3' style="overflow:visible;">
        <h2>EPs</h2>
        <div class='row2'>
            <a href="...">
                <img width="300px" src="..."/>
                <h2>Nano Miratus</h2>
                <h3>Mrs. EP</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you look at the Releases Section, you will see there is this title ("2014"). Left and right to this titles are arrows, or carets I think they are called. :D

What I wanted to code is:
When someone clicks on the right arrow, the div with the id "2014" should fade out in 4000 milliseconds, then the div with the id "2015" should fade in in 4000 milliseconds. I put a delay before the fade in of that "2015" div. It's also 4000 milliseconds, so the fade in of "2015" should start right after the fade out of "2014" has finished.

What really happens is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxLVB.gif

---

So why isn't it working? I googled and stackoverflowed so much in the last hours and changed that code so often, but it still doesn't work. :(

**UPDATE:**
Now I know what the problem is, but I can't solve it. This website is a single page website, so I have a javascript plugin. It's called fullpage.js and I know how it works. When you scroll with your mouse, it adds an "transform: translate3d(x, y, z);" property to the "page-container fullpage-wrapper", and changes the y-value, so the page goes down. So I made two fiddles for a demonstration of the problem:

**NOT WORKING FIDDLE (with the transform property in it):**

jsfiddle.net/ktf9onjo/ (sorry, I'm not allowed to post more then two clickable links...)

**WORKING FIDDLE:**

jsfiddle.net/rant5af9/

You see that the problem is the transform property.

1. WHY???
2. I need an alternative. I cannot just remove it, the script will
   be readd it every time I scroll.
3. Yeah, I could just change the translate3d(x, y, z) to a translateY(y), but nooo, that isn't working, I tried it. :D

INFO: You can find the fullpage.js in the javascript box in both fiddles.

PS: The website isn't finished yet. A lot of links and other things aren't working at the moment.

Please help, fanx! :)

Comment: Could you make a fiddle for this?

Comment: Instead of using `onclick`, does it work if you delegate a 'click' event to div#forward2014?  `$('#forward2014').on('click', function () {
  $("#2014").fadeOut(4000);
 })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why the problem happens

As explained by @kosmos in comment:

> Because the queue for animations is for every element animation itself. `a` won't wait for `b` to make its animation, but if you try to animate `a` two times, the second animation will wait for the end of the first one.

#### Solution

jQuery `fadeOut` function accepts a `complete` callback function ([source](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)).

This callback function is executed once the fade-out is complete. You don't need to use `delay` anymore this way, and your animations chaining will keep in sync.

html:

```
<div id="forward2014" style="display:inline-block">
```

javascript:

```
$('#forward2014').click(function(){
  $("#2014").fadeOut(4000, function(){
    // this starts when the fadeOut is finished
    $("#2015").fadeIn(4000);
  })

});
```

#### demo in this snippet

(click the `>>` as forward button)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#2015").hide();

  
  $('#forward2014').click(function(){
  
    $("#2014").fadeOut(4000, function(){
    
      // this starts when the fadeOut is finished
    
      $("#2015").fadeIn(4000);
  
    })

  });
});
```

```html
<div id="2014"style="display:inline-block">
2014
</div>
<div id="2015"style="display:inline-block">
2015
</div>
<div id="forward2014">
>>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Further remarks:

- You may want to use jQuery's `.on` function for event listeners ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). You can replace the `onclick=` and the `.click` by it. This should make your code easier to manage and more performant.
- The ids in your html are supposed to contain at least a letter ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1006854)). Replace `id="2014"` by `id="year-2014"` or something like that.

Comment: Because the queue for animations is for every element animation itself. `a` won't wait for `b` to make its animation, but if you try to animate `a` two times, the second animation will wait for the end of the first one. So the OP need to use the callback functions provided by these methods.

Comment: It's still not working. :(
The "2014" fades out and then nothing's there for 4000 millseconds and then the "2015" pops in. Like in the gif I shared in my question.

Comment: @NanoMiratus I have added explanations plus a snippet to demonstrate that/how it works. Cannot help further if you don't share your code in a snippet or fiddle...

Comment: Hi mef! Firstly, sorry. I'm new to this site and I don't know yet how to use it correctly, haha. Secondly, I'm really new to jquery and javascript, i self-learned it two days ago, so my question probably sounded dumb or so, sorry. Thirdly, I'm 16 years old, from Austria. My english isn't very good, but I tried my best. Sorry again.

It's really great here on Stack Overflow that everyone tries helping, nevertheless how complicated the question is. Thank you all!

When I'm back home I'll try to implement your feedback in my html page. Till later then! :)

Comment: Hi again! So now I know what the problem is. But I can't solve it. I updated the question, please take a look at it. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? The forward button seems to work correctly in both the fiddles ( tried in firefox and chromium). You should still remove the `onclick` in the html, it causes as it's calling an unexisting function.

Comment: The FadeIn does still not work. It pops in. I am using chrome.

Comment: You did not reply to the question "What do you mean by "it is not working"?"

Comment: Sorry @mef. The fadeIn is not working. That is what I mean. It fades out correctly but then there is nothing and the second element just pops in, it does not **fade** in. Btw, I visited the website with an iPhone today, there the fadeIn works. I still think it's because of that "transform: ..." thing.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you have described when running the "not working" fiddle you have created. The problem doesn't seem to happend in your iPhone, as you have mentioned. In which web browser do you see the problem?

Comment: In Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m.

Comment: I can't help you with this problem, sorry, doesn't reproduce on my end.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't got what you need exactly but to make to jquery actions going sequences you must call the second action with call back like this

```
$('#whatever').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#whatever').delay(4000).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

[See This](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)